# Case statement being a pain

Tags: php, sql

My code creates a table in a database,  based on the name and date provided by the user (imagine all the values aren't repeated), it will create a database for only the first "user" (First name you can select from the drop down box) but no others? can post other `sql` code but don't think that is the issue.

```
switch ($Name) {
   case "Ben":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Tom":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Tom":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Ben":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Tom":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Ben":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Tom":
      ct($Name, $Date);
      break;
   case "Ben":
      ct($Name, $Date);
    }
}

?>
```

```
<!-- Allows User to who they are -->
<p>You are: </p><form action="" method="post">
<select name="name" id="name">
  <option value="RoryRedfearn">Rory Redfearn</option>
  <option value="ChrisParner">Chris Parner</option>
  <option value="JamesBarnes">James Barnes</option>
</select>
```

The function:

```
function ct($Name, $Date) {

//Takes inputed data and stores it in variables
$Car  = isset($_POST['car']) ? trim($_POST['car']) :'';
$Night = isset($_POST['yes']) ? trim($_POST['yes']) :'';
$Siteid = isset($_POST['siteid']) ? trim($_POST['siteid']) :'';
$LHA = isset($_POST['stepExample1']) ? trim($_POST['stepExample1']) :'';
$AAS = isset($_POST['stepExample2']) ? trim($_POST['stepExample2']) :'';
$LS = isset($_POST['stepExample3']) ? trim($_POST['stepExample3']) :'';

//Database information
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "people";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";

//connects to our database
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
    $table = "" .$Name. " ". $Date . "";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$table."` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Car VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Night VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Siteid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LHA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
AAS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)";

$sq = $link->query($sql);
//Prepares inputed data for insertion  
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(Name, Car, Night, Date, Siteid, LHA,    AAS, LS)
VALUES(:Name, :Car, :Night, :Date, :Siteid, :LHA, :AAS, :LS)");
try {
  $statement->execute(array(
    "Name" => $Name,
    "Car" => $Car,
    "Night" => $Night,
    "Date" => $Date,
    "Siteid" => $Siteid,
    "LHA" => $LHA,
    "AAS" => $AAS,
    "LS" => $LS,
  ));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Exception caught: $e";
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Its all a little vague.

Comment: My code creates a table in a database, based on the name and date provided by the user (imagion all the values arnt repeated), it will create a database for only the first "user" (First name you can select from the drop down box) but no others? can post other sql code but dont think that is the issue.

Comment: and where is Ben in your dropdown?

Comment: You have repeated cases... doesn't make much sense. Also, if it always the same action, why bothering using distinct cases?

Comment: What does the function `ct` do?

Comment: I am aware, they have peoples names on (Not going to post that) so coppied them down, function creates a table, based on the passed values,

Comment: So you're creating a table for each user/date combo...  Out of curiosity, why?  I can't think of any reason to do this.

Comment: More than one user & date combo, easyier to sort the data, lots of fields, if you have a better way feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `switch` if there is still same code repeated?

```
if (in_array($Name, ['Ben', 'Tom']) {
   ct($Name, $Date);
}
```

Suggested database structure (doing as all others):

```
[user]
 id  |  Name  |  Surname
  1     Ben       Afflec
  2     Tom       Gandolfini

[data]
  id  | UserID | Car | Night | Date
   1      1      Yes     Yes    No
   2      2      No      Yes    No
```

Then query will be easier to maintain

```
SELECT Car FROM data WHERE userID IN (1, 2);
```

Comment: Good idea thank you, but still not the answer, problems creating the tables based on the $name and $date variable.

Comment: @Danturnip So if you currently have `Ben` as `$Name`, than you create table named `Ben` and with it's data. But consider better approach, since creating new table for each user is bad idea. Better save `users` to same table and `user_data` to other, adding `user_id` to `user_data` table

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion its a good idea. But then i a table i will have numerous repeated fields, for example LHA, each user has to fill that in each day 5/6 times a week. I dont get much time to work on this project you see, so i dont have much time to setup / get my head around linking all the data.

Comment: @Danturnip the selection of the data is the same, how do you select the table? just select the right data ;) stub: (`SELECT everythingInteresting FROM data WHERE userName = 'Ben' AND date = 'yourDateYouWantToShow' `)

Comment: Your code worked, i will defintly look into using your method of storing data, i dont often get time to work on this at work (For work, but not employed as a software guy) so i did it the way i knew from college, thank you :)

Comment: @Danturnip Yes, there may be lots of info in database, that's why use it. You will have more problems with different tables, than with more data. How much data you are expecting? 10 000 000 entries and more?

Comment: See above, Once i have this up and running (Needed soon as, given no time), i will look into changing to your method of storing data (obviously far superior), but i would need more time to get my head around it, also its going to be exported to excel.

Comment: @Danturnip Yes, you are trying to make to work some odd solution, that will take lots of time to implement, will make your system useless and will bring even more time consuming situations/errors. Instead you could use the right solution with much less time consumed.